# loop in php script executes by asterisk

Tags: php, while-loop, asterisk

My idea is that I want to execute a PHP script in Asterisk's dial-plan. It works like a deamon/process that gets values from the Asterisk and does something with them. But when I do the **system(php script.php)** command Asterisk stops and does not go to the next dial-plan step. The reason is that, I believe, the *script.php* has "while(1) {...}" loop inside and Asterisk waits for its end...

Could you help me and show me some solution how to run external "php-loop" script and go through extensions.conf steps at one time?

*extensions.conf*

```
[internal]
exten => 100,1,Set(CallerId=${CALLERID(num)}) ;get number
exten => 100,n,System(php script.php ${CallerId}) ;execute php script with argv[1]
;now the script.php should run at the background and below part
;should be execute like in ordinary context
exten => 100,n,Dial(SIP/100)
exten => 100,n,Hangup()
```

*script.php*

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  $num = argv[1]; //the value from [internal] in the extensions.conf
  while(1) { //start the loop
  /*
   * do something in the infinite loop and END it IF something happen
   * e.g. $someVal == 9999;
  */
  }
?>
```

So, as you can see the idea is simple: start the php script with the 'loop' and in meantime do something else from the bottom steps in the [internal] context.
How to handle it? Because Asterisk waits for the end of the *script.php* execution and then he goes to the next step.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Agi's in Asterisk are blocking. Dialplan execution will wait until the agi dies before continuing. If you want your agi to run regardless of the Dialplan, look in to Fastagi, which is an agi deamon that you connect to via a socket (its long living, irrespective and independent of Asterisk). Just dont forget to set ${AGISIGHUP}=no in your dialplan BEFORE calling the agi.

For examples of AGI's see [here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI) and check out some the scripts included in [FreePBX's](http://www.freepbx.org) many modules.